# Looking for a scifi/fantasy book about children who win a war by a trick

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a scifi/fantasy book that I read 3 or 4 years ago. I cant remember all the details but it involves some war against beings of destruction or chaos where children rally up in one last battle where they win by a trick. I think these children had special abilities that gave them the upper hand. There was also something about a village and an inescapable forest.

I am pretty sure there are at least five books and that this is a series. This story also has something about a old powerplant stations. (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like "[Ender's Game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ender%27s_Game)" by Orson Scott Card.

Comment: That's it. I think I got the detail about the powerplant wrong though. But sounds pretty much how I described it.

Comment: The recognition is yours, of course.  But to me, for one, your question sounds **nothing like** the _Ender's Game_ books.  It's at odds with the books on practically every point, although Milagre is sometimes termed a village.

Comment: @JdeBP I suspect the memory of a village and an inescapable forest is the Giant's Drink game from _Ender's Game_.